# To what extent can we monitor jobs as DBO in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk, dbo

Short Background:

I work for company A, at company A we have a DBA that should not be. When we are tasked with items for troubleshooting which require quick turn around, it generally takes quite a bit longer than it should.

For this reason, we asked him to grant me DBO access to certain servers (Biztalk SQL servers). I'm the one who is dropping files and monitoring this stuff, sometimes overnight, and lately we have been experiencing system slow down.

So with these issues with Biztalk, I've gone into the SQL server and tried to dig around but it seems most of them require higher priveleges then I have. I've looked for suspended queries, killed them, but as DBO, I was wondering what's the extent I can monitor and find out about the jobs currently running/suspended.

I am familiar with `exec sp_who2` and `kill %%` but other than that I've been hitting a wall...

My question:

Are there any useful features I can utilize as DBO that will assist in identifying the cause of these suspended queries? Other than who and who2?

Any homegrown queries you folks have wrote for identifying such causes of these errors?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at using the [Performance Analysis of Logs (PAL) Tool for BizTalk 2006](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296652.aspx) or [BizTalk 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308953%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) if your issues are ongoing.